# Terminal display of input goes out of sync while/after using python? (temporary fix = `reset`)

Tags: python, macos, bash, macports, xterm

Every time that I run `python` or `python3` with an interactive console, the display of the prompt gets out of sync almost immediately after the first or second interaction:

```
>>> [1,2,3]
>>> [1, 2, 3]
print('hi')
>>> hi
```

Then, when I exit out of python, this behavior carries over to `bash`, with the addition that when you type, nothing appears on the screen, but it will still run. In the following example, I typed `date` and then `history | tail -n3`:

```
$ Thu Oct  8 07:55:47 CEST 2015
$   488  python
  489  date
  490  history | tail -n3
```

However, after typing `reset`, everything goes back to normal.

Needless to say, this behavior is very annoying. What is the cause, and how can I fix it?

I am on OS X. Using iTerm or built-in Terminal.app both give the same behavior. My python builds are from `macports`. This problem is not present with `/usr/bin/python` (python 2.7.2, included with OS X).

============================

**Edit:** If I use `zsh`, then python still has problems, but everything works fine in `zsh` after I exit out of python.

`$TERM` is `xterm-256color` in both `bash` and `zsh`.

Comment: Probably your python that outputs control characters and that changes the configuration of your terminal. Might be in the python banner. You can try to `s=$(stty -g)` before launching python and `stty $s` after, to save and restore the terminal configuration. But it will not help during your python interactive session...

Comment: how do you exit python?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGutiérrez I have tried exiting with ctrl+D and `exit()` and both yield the same result.

Comment: What's your `$TERM` variable set to (`echo $TERM`)?

Comment: @Stebalien I added $TERM to the question. It is xterm-256color.

Comment: Please run  `sudo port selfupdate`, `sudo port upgrade outdated`, `python -V`, `python3 -V`, and then `echo $BASH_VERSION` and post the output of the last three here. If you haven't switched your default shell to MacPorts's, then follow the instructions [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/70189/72652) before running these commands.

Comment: @Coder256 `Python 2.7.10` `Python 3.4.3` `4.3.42(1)-release`, and behavior is the same.

Comment: You aren't using xterm though. I assume you are setting `TERM` manually? Does this problem happen if you *don't* do that?

Comment: @EtanReisner I do not set `$TERM` in my profile. Terminal.app and iTerm.app both have settings to declare the terminal type. I have never changed that setting, so I assume that `xterm-256color` is the most popular default. I can also declare as `ansi`, `dtterm`, `nsterm`, `rxvt`, `vt52`, `vt100`, `vt102`, `xterm`, or `xterm-16color`. I tried using `ansi` and `xterm` on Terminal.app and I get the same behavior.

Comment: `TERM` is `xterm-256color` out of the box in the built-in Terminal at least on Yosemite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in my answer in [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/207171/237) there was a bug in recent python builds under Macports when the question was written due to this [Macports bug](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/48807?cversion=0&cnum_hist=11) as it was not including readline (for license reasons)

This has now been fixed by making a +readline variant and making this the default

Answer (score 1):

Try the `stty sane` command in shell.

Answer (score 1):

@Mark has the explanation.

As for the fix:

```
port selfupdate
# port install python(26|27|34|35) +readline
port install python27 +readline
```